# Jquery show/hide div area on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm trying to return a PHP array on a selection menu.

For example: User selects the gender inside the selection, now the JS should call a PHP class to return a array of items. And JS should add the values from the array to another selection menu.

In case the user selects another gender now, the PHP class should be called again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#fds_gender').change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "stud") {
                <?php
                    require_once('../handling/fds_categorys.php');
                    $fds_stealer = new fds_categorys($user->username, 'stud');
                    $data = $fds_stealer->get_template_categories();
                ?>
            }else if($(this).val() == "babe") {
                <?php
                    require_once('../handling/fds_categorys.php');
                    $fds_stealer = new fds_categorys($user->username, 'babe');
                    $data = $fds_stealer->get_template_categories();
                ?>
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label>Categories</label>
    <select name="categorie" data-placeholder="Select a categorie..." class="select-icons">
        <?php foreach($data['categories'] as $categorie): ?>
            <?php echo '<option value="' . $categorie['name'] . '" data-icon="woman">' . $categorie['name'] . '</option>'; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Sadly the selection only contains the `else if` response and would not change on another selection.

Does anyone have a idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: using php inside of script tags is a terrible idea. You should be using `AJAX` to `POST` and `GET` data from a server using a separate php file.

Comment: you cant do it that way. When you have mix HTML, JS/Jquery and  PHP code  in a page the PHP code executes 1st and then the rest. So you cant mix Jquery and php and have it run whenever you want. You can however create a separate php file and execute php code to produce some results and send the data back to the page using ajax -- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ -- you could also POST a form to the same PHP page by submitting it to the same page but i dont think anyone does that anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP runs on server-side, so requiring it inside a javascript if/else will only load stuff twice at startup. (If you check the source code, your if/else is empty)

That said you have 2 different approaches here.

### First Approach

The server-side approach is loading everything at startup and assembling 2 javascript arrays with your different datasets.

```
   <?php
      require_once('../handling/fds_categorys.php');
      $fds_stealer = new fds_categorys($user->username, 'stud');
      $dataStud = array_map(
         function($el){
            return $el['name'];
         },
         $fds_stealer->get_template_categories()
      );
      $fds_stealer = new fds_categorys($user->username, 'babe');
      $dataBabe = array_map(
         function($el){
            return $el['name'];
         },
         $fds_stealer->get_template_categories()
      )
   ?>
   var dataStud = ["<?= implode('"', $dataStud) ?>"];
   var dataBabe = ["<?= implode('"', $dataBabe) ?>"];
```

Now you have 2 javascript arrays with your data.
On change you would use jquery to assemble the options of your select.

### Second Approach

Using Ajax to call a file which returns you the JSON array.
It's a whole other world so you would have to research a little before I could give you any code about this.
But basically you will have to have a .php in your server that gets parameters (either via $_GET or $_POST) and returns a JSON array.
Call $.post or $.get in jQuery and in the callback function you would populate the options of your select.
The $.get or $.post call would run everytime you change the select value.

Comment: You explained this much better than I did, great job! I personally would prefer the ajax/JSON solution, but that really depends on your preferred work method.

Comment: @JohnnyKutnowski Thank you. I preffer the ajax way too. Server is just an API, the navigation and rendering is all javascript :P

Comment: Doing the ajax way now. Gotta try around with the response alil more actually. https://gyazo.com/ec932d15fcf0f5a43b5be1af5a503585

Comment: Gone this way now: 1) Created another PHP file to create a PHP class object and call the function, 2) Create the ajax to post variables to the PHP file which returns the array: http://pastebin.com/ehxZ0ibs

Comment: @d4ne Did you `echo` out your `json_encode($data)` array thing yet? :P The server only needs a single parameter string whose value will be either 'stud' or 'babe'.

Answer (score 1):

You must understand -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#fds_gender').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "stud") {
            <?php
                require_once('../handling/fds_categorys.php');
                $fds_stealer = new fds_categorys($user->username, 'stud');
                $data = $fds_stealer->get_template_categories();
            ?>
        }else if($(this).val() == "babe") {
            <?php
                require_once('../handling/fds_categorys.php');
                $fds_stealer = new fds_categorys($user->username, 'babe');
                $data = $fds_stealer->get_template_categories();
            ?>
        }
    });
});
```

below PHP script will be excecuted on the server side and server dont care about the javascript and HTML So this will not work.

```
<?php
            require_once('../handling/fds_categorys.php');
            $fds_stealer = new fds_categorys($user->username, 'stud');
            $data = $fds_stealer->get_template_categories();
        ?>
```

Rather you should make a AJAX call from jquery for and then hide/show the div using jquery methods .hide() .show()

```
require_once('../handling/fds_categorys.php');
            $fds_stealer = new fds_categorys($user->username, 'stud');
            $data = $fds_stealer->get_template_categories();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because PHP is interpreted before the page even loads, while jQuery manipulates the DOM, after that is done.

Therefore, what you are doing will not work.

You could have the `select` tag be part of a form that makes a request to a PHP page on change, and have the PHP do the logic (like a standard MVC app) and return the values.

Then, with the returned values, manipulate them to render as you want them on the DOM.

Comment: Not necessarily. It just means that php will always render the results for both cases, which might be ok, although I suspect not...

Comment: I said "might". It could be that `require_once` is not what is intended, so that could be the error.

Comment: @bukko, the require is there to load his class.
Then he uses his class twice, overriding the vars as he runs things twice in server-side. (the `require_once` is the least of his problems the `once` part will take care of that)

Comment: That's right, which could be his error. Maybe he just wanted `require` not `require_once` - ? As I said, it's just a possibility. Most likely he misunderstood server-side vs client-side.

Comment: Even if he uses "require" it would only override his vars and give him a fatal error when trying to define the same class twice, still his javascript if/else would be empty (his code doesn't render anything, only sets the `$data` var).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign php results into JS array and then convert it into select options.

```
var dataJson;

if ($(this).val() == "stud") {
        <?php
            require_once('../handling/fds_categorys.php');
            $fds_stealer = new fds_categorys($user->username, 'stud');
            $data = $fds_stealer->get_template_categories();
            echo 'dataJson = "'.json_encode($data).'"';
        ?>
}
//convert json array into JS array
var dataArray = JSON.parse(dataJson),
    options = '';
//iterate converted array to grab option names
for (var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    options += '<option>'+dataArray[i].name+'</option>';
}
//now populate dropdown with values
$(this).html(options);
```

Comment: No real reason. It's because there is a serial down-voter on this question.

Answer (score -1):

For a start...

```
}else if($(this).val() == "babe") {
```

...looks wrong. Your `if` should be inside brackets.

Secondly, your `require_once` statement will be rendered twice, so this is clearly not what you intend.

You need to learn the order that your code will be processed, i.e.:

1. Server side code (PHP)
2. Client side code (Javascript/jQuery)

If you want to update your page without refreshing it, you will need to make an Ajax call from your client-side script to another PHP script on the server.

[This link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) shows you one way to do it from jQuery.

Comment: Only problem with that would be the PHP class structure. Could I call a function in a file directly using Ajax? And yea ur totally right about the require_once.

Comment: Ok but you should vote down poor quality answers, not those you don't like. Mine also pointed out the javascript error, which nobody else has...

Comment: In PHP you call a file from Ajax in the same way you do from your browser, just use the URL for the file in your POST/GET call.

Comment: Í did not down-vote ur answer i cant even vote yet. Need 15 rep to do that.

Comment: Ah, ok I apologise (it's been a long time!). Are you ok with coding your Ajax call?

Comment: Yes, just been looking into it and i guess ill have to code a extra file which build the object first then calls the function inside the class. So ajax could grab the response. Am i right?

Comment: Absolutely right. Ajax is great, it makes pages much more seamless. You can do loads of cool page rebuilding without refreshing the browser. Also jQuery is perfect to do it with. Good luck and have fun :)